# Python Replace Blanks With Letter

Tags: python, replace

I want the letters the user types (granted that they're in the 'letters') to replace the blanks in their correct sequential position (I don't want 'agbdf__'), and stop when all the letters are typed in. As the code is now, it requires letters to be typed multiple times, and it stops if the letter 'g' is typed seven times. This is a part of a hangman code I'm trying to implement. If anyone could post the right way to program this (not just a tip, because I most likely won't be able to figure out how to implement it), it would be much appreciated.

```
letters='abcdefg' 
blanks='_'*len(letters) 
print('type letters from a to g')
print(blanks)
for i in range(len(letters)):
    if letters[i] in input(): 
        blanks = blanks[:i] + letters[i] + blanks[i+1:]
        print(blanks)
```

Comment: Just because your [other question was closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544747/python-replace-blanks/18546170#18546170) doesn't mean you can repeat it and create a duplicate.

Comment: You didn't provide any explanation with the answer you gave me, and the people who responded in that question were very impolite. So pardon me if I ask it again and get answers that actually help me, Burhan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
for i in range(len(letters)):
    letter = raw_input()
    index = letters.index(letter)
    blanks = blanks[:index] + letter + blanks[index + 1:]
    print blanks
```

You are not replacing the correct blank/underscore, you are just sequentially replacing them. Instead you need to find the correct blank to replace, and then replace that. Also don't expect this code to be running infinitely until the blanks is completely filled. If you want that, you can figure that out I guess (as your question is specific to replacing correct letters). Also you might want this program should handle inputs other than 'abcdef' too :).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been trying to learn to do for a while. Could you tell me what it's called when you link variables with the '.' so I can look it up? Or, if you have the time to tell me what exactly the '.' is doing in this code , could you?

Comment: the `.` is not linking variables. its calling a variable/method that belongs to the object. You should maybe visit some python tutorial websites, as this is day one programming knowledge.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the program to keep running if more than 7 letters are typed. I know its probably easy but I can't seem to get it. Anyone mind helping me with this part?

Comment: @user2734880, We are looping through the `letters` so if you want to forgive say 3 chances, you can: `for i in range(len(letters) + 3):`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension for this. Here's an example:

```
letters = 'abcdefg'
typed = raw_input('Type the characters a through g: ')
print ''.join(s if s in typed else '_' for s in letters)
```

Sample Output:

```
Type the characters a through g: abdef
ab_def_
```

Here's a more complete/advanced hangman example: https://gist.github.com/dbowring/6419866

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = 'abcdefg' 

print('type letters from a to g')

all_letters = list(letters)
blanks = ['_'] * len(letters) 

while True:
    guessed_letter = input("guess > ")

    while guessed_letter in all_letters:
        index = all_letters.index(guessed_letter)
        all_letters[index] = None
        blanks[index] = guessed_letter

    output = ''.join(blanks)
    print(output)

    if letters == output:
        print("gg")
        break
```

Or if you prefere a more stringy version

```
letters = 'abcdefg' 

print('type letters from a to g')

all_letters = list(letters)
blanks = '_' * len(letters) 

while True:
    guessed_letter = input("guess > ")

    while guessed_letter in all_letters:
        index = all_letters.index(guessed_letter)
        all_letters[index] = None       
        blanks = blanks[:index] + guessed_letter + blanks[index+1:]

    print(blanks)

    if letters == blanks:
        print("gg")
        break
```